# Accessible Tagged PDF with BIRT

Tags: eclipse, accessibility, birt, tagged-pdf

We are using BIRT to create PDF-files from our website, but now we need to change the PDFs to meet the accessibility demands. I have tried to search for an answer how to make accessible tagged PDF with BIRT, but haven't found any answer. Even this https://www.eclipse.org/birt/ documentation doesn't talk about accessibility nor making tagged PDF.
So is it possible to add tags with BIRT or do we need to change BIRT to some completely different tool? If we need to change the tool, I would much appreciate info about tool which we could use. We have quite many PDF templates created with BIRT and all need to be changed to meet the accessibility demands.

Answer (score 0):

With the Open Source version of BIRT, creating tagged PDFs is not possible AFAIK.

However, in a BIRT IDE built from source, it looks as if development in this direction started (IIRC there were "PDF Tag" properties in the advanced properties).

Maybe the commercial BIRT version from OpenText can generate tagged PDFs - I don't know and I would really appreciate more info about this topic from the BIRT project.

Edit: According to http://otadocs.opentext.com/documentation/ihub3/help/adg/adg24/index.html#page/ADG/DesigningReport.1.03.html#, this should be possible with the commercial version.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! We have the Open Source version of BIRT at the moment and we definitely need to check this commercial version of BIRT. This seems to be the latest version of it https://actuate-birt-designer-professional.software.informer.com/